# Open source frameworksto generate graphical reports?

Tags: android, report, core-plot

Can any one suggest me any open source framework to generate reports in android apps? (Some thing like 'Core-plot' for iPhone development)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**iText is available for android, although I don't know how stable it is:**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextpdfandroid/

**There are several chart libraries for android:**

http://android.arnodenhond.com/components/graphview

http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing

http://www.java4less.com/charts/chart.php?info=android

http://androidplot.com/wiki/Quickstart

http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/

http://www.keepedge.com/

And Femi just posted a link to a related question, so I will stop here.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android for an existing discussion.

Comment: Hi Femi, Thanks for quick reply. I will go through the above link , It is very helpful for me if any examples are available?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org). It includes a bunch of chart types, a lot of demo code and is free to use for both free or commercial applications.